# SQL : How sysdate minus a value works?

Tags: sql, oracle, where-clause

I found below code in my existing project.

```
select * from mytable where SomeColumn_date >= trunc(sysdate)-.25/24;
```

Sample value for `SomeColumn_date` is `22-JUN-17 05:46:55`

How does `SomeColumn_date >= trunc(sysdate)-.25/24` work on Date data type?

Comment: I would use dateadd rather - more verbose and clear AND supports all date formats, i.e. also datetime2.

Comment: @AnthonyHorne, he's using oracle, not sql server

Comment: one other more readable way, would be something like:   select * from mytable where SomeColumn_date >= trunc(sysdate) - interval '15' minute

Comment: @RenatoAfonso Thanks - Oracle tag added after my comment :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Different database engines allow different operations to be applied to `date` data types.  For the most part, an operation of `<Date Value> +/- 1` will add or subtract one day to that date value.  This is syntactically equivalent to the `dateadd` function when using `days`.

In your example here, the `-.25/24` resolves to the number equivalent of `-15 minutes`, which is then subtracted from your date value.

It is essentially a much less readable version of `datedd(min,-15,<Date Value>)`.

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation of [`TRUNC`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions201.htm) (I'm guessing you are using Oracle):

> The TRUNC (date) function returns date with the time portion of the day truncated to the unit specified by the format model fmt. [...] If you omit fmt, then date is truncated to the nearest day.

The result of `trunc(sysdate)` would be the present date without the time component. Now `.25/24` (actually meaning `0.25/24`) is substracted from that. If you substract a date using `-` the operand is always in days. `0.25/24` would be a form to express a quarter of an hour.

So `trunc(sysdate)-.25/24` would result in yesterday 23:45.

Comment: 'The result of trunc(sysdate) would be the present date without the time component.' - this is crucial!

The sentence from the documentation is misleading - 'If you omit fmt, then date is truncated to the nearest day.' I would assume that if we do TRUNC on a date with time like - 27-OCT-92 23:59:59 - then 'the nearest day' is 28-OCT-92..

Answer (score 0):

Ok so 2 things are happening here:

```
 trunk(date,fmt)
```

The TRUNC (date) function returns date with the time portion of the day truncated to the unit specified by the format model fmt. If you omit fmt, then date is truncated to the nearest day.

So **if you have suppose 22-JUN-17 05:46:55 you get 22-JUN-17**. Since you don't have the fmt

---

`DATETIME - .25/24` implies .25 hours before your current Date time.

But since you have only DATE all it does is .25 hours before todays 12:00 AM i.e yesterdays 11:45PM

---

```
SomeColumn_date >= trunc(sysdate)-.25/24
```

So suppose if its 22-JUN-2017 right now the date is compared to 21-JUN-2017 11:45 PM

NOTE: - is for before current time, + is for after the current time